# iOS Parse Server set server url at runtime without application restart

Tags: parse-platform

I tried to set a new parse server url while inside the app, but there was no change what so ever.

```
Parse.server = @"https://serverNewUrl.com"; or [Parse setServer:@"https://serverNewUrl.com"];
NSLog(@"%@",Parse.server); -----> This prints the new server set
NSLog(@"%@",Parse.currentConfiguration.server); -----> This prints the old one set
```

How did you achieve the change ? Parse iOS SDK 1.18

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the initialize function. I believe it should work even if you use it a second time to change the server URL.

```swift
        let parseConfig = ParseClientConfiguration {
            $0.applicationId = "parseAppId"
            $0.clientKey = "parseClientKey"
            $0.server = "parseServerUrlString"
        }
        Parse.initialize(with: parseConfig)
```

Comment: No, the application crashes since you can't initialize Parse twice